# Using @ sign in comments to call out users makes it difficult to discuss certain iOS topics

Tags: support, comments

Using an @ sign in the comments allows you to notify another user to direct your comment at that person.  For example, someone might comment @WolfLink.  However, this makes it difficult to discuss certain iOS topics:

- @2x and @3x images
- `@"NSString Literals"` (and other literals like `@5` or `@[@1,@2]` and so on)

How can I use an @ sign in the comments without it registering as targeting a user?

Comment: Does formatting as `@"code"` not work? It seems to have worked `@2` times for me here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where appropriate, you can format the at-sign-containing phrase as code using backticks:

> You can't add a literal string like `@"This is my string"` to a literal `NSNumber` like `@2`.

For non-code items, it's often appropriate to mark them off with quotes:

> You've got to append the "@3x" to the filename itself.

In other cases, any non-whitespace character placed immediately before the "@" will stop it from being parsed as a ping, so a workaround is to pretend-escape it:

> My Twitter handle is \@WolfLink, @user5551212.

although this will render with the backslash included.

Comment: You can't add a literal string like `@"This is my string"` to a literal `NSNumber` like `@2`.

Comment: You've got to append the "@3x" to the filename itself.

Comment: My Twitter handle is \@WolfLink, @user5551212.