# A dot makes mentions (`@`) work funny

Tags: bug, comment-replies

I just received a ping in my notifications that a comment was addressed to me. Nothing odd about that, it's just that [said comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804827/are-these-two-codes-doing-the-same-thing?noredirect=1#comment84615256_48804827) addressed me with a `@` second. (Recording the comment here, in case the post goes 10k only)

> I am still not clear. The firstcase assigns ptr as a pointer to the
>   first element of array. The second case is also assignig a pointer arr
>   to array.@SouravGhosh @StoryTeller

In my understanding, only the first user being mentioned is actually addressed. So this caught me by surprise.

Is this a new feature, or some bug<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Despite my initial excitement, it's in fact a buggy feature. The sequence `.@` prevents `@` from being interpreted as a user mention. But the auto-complete works...</sub>

Comment: hypothesis: I wonder whether the `.@` meant that 
the first mention wan't interpreted as a mention

Comment: @MarcGravell - Well, I'm starting to feel silly

Comment: _@StoryTeller_ @Marc : I'm often use a comment format like this, to make it clear I also want to address the OP. May be you met that from someone else.

Comment: @TheDude - I linked to the original comment. The other person that was mentioned isn't the OP. In fact, it was the OP writing that comment.

Comment: Just to confirm: you were notified, Sourav was not (moderators can see your responses tab).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I guess ultimately that's my answer

Comment: @MartijnPieters something something answers as comments

Comment: @StoryTeller answer aside, this feature really ought to be added to the network. It's massively useful.

Comment: @TylerH - I totally agree with you. My own haste in posting was due to excitement about the possibility of this already happening :)

Comment: test .@MarcGravell will you get notified or will @MartijnPieters only get a notification?

Comment: cc @MarcGravell ^^

Comment: @Tanner I didn't get the first notification

Comment: I don't believe that this is a bug. Any leading character has always acted as an escape and prevented notification: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303565/603977

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I do believe punctuations should be exempt. Not all people add a space after a punctuation consistently. Whether or not it's a problem on their part is immaterial. It's an innocent mistake that can easily prevent proper communication between users on a post.

Comment: .@JoshCaswell since the auto-completion feature seems to allow such leading character, it is a bug of at least one of the features.

Comment: The comment was edited. Was another person `@` added after edit (you was initially, thus you got the ping)? How ping works for edits of comments?

Comment: @Sinatr - The bug was reproduced in the comments here. It's not a ninja edit problem.

Comment: This question is really confusing when read top-to-bottom with no knowledge of its history. Could you edit it to be a single, self-contained, coherent, clear question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It was fairly rambling an excited when I originally posted. Didn't really expect it to blow up so much. I edited it to what is (hopefully) a more coherent phrasing, that doens't invalidate the accepted answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good work, thanks! Now you're telling a story :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/209901):

> The notification must begin with a space or be at the start of the comment.

So `.@` does not accomplish the `(\s|^)@` pattern and hence does not trigger the notification.

Comment: Up-voted. But then like Kaiido points out, it shouldn't suggest to autocomplete with a user's name.

Comment: .@StoryTeller agreed (did you get the notification? <-- joking, you got it because no one else commented here :P)

Comment: I never expected regular expressions here!

Comment: Wow, that's a great example of a terrible regex. What's wrong with `\b`? Or, y'know, _not using regexes_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unless I've missed something, I don't see any indication in that thread of what the regex they actually use is, or even if they do. (Although how else would you do it?) `\b` wouldn't work as `@` isn't a word character...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey, wait a second.  Not using regexes?  Next you'll suggest we don't dereference dangling pointers to save on memory allocations (after all, using memory through a dangling pointer saves on new allocations).  Madness.

Comment: @Yakk: I know, right? Where will it end?!

Comment: @Rawling: Okay, "Wow, that's a great example of a terrible piece of logic, that you happen to have rendered in the form of a regex". Not sure what `@`'s got to do with it; the `\b` is for matching the non-word characters _before_ the `@`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see why? `\b` is **not** the same as `(\s|^)` since it matches in many more cases...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit AFAIK it is intended to work like that, otherwise somebody writing a comment in, say, Haskell will notify people when writing a snippet of code using `@`-patterns like `f g@NothingToSee = 5`, and poor the guy who will register with name `Transactional`... will be notified way too much if he is into Java.

Comment: Snippets of code should be surrounded by backticks, just as you did in your comment. If someone uses `@` inside a comment without backticks and they meant to write code, there are still plenty of chances for that to result in a notification, with the logic as it is now. That is really not a good reason to silently break notifications in other cases, like this (@GiacomoAlzetta)

Comment: Actually, having said that, I can't see any mention of backticks in that other answer, though my experience is that they do suppress notifications. I wonder which is true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `\b` matches a boundary between a word char and a non-word char. Thus it won't match e.g. in the middle of ` @` as that's two non-word chars.

Comment: @Rawling: Derp. Okay `(?!<\W)@` then! My point is that I think individually whitelisting characters is the wrong approach, particularly when limiting it to only _one_ of them (plus start-of-line).

Comment: Well, let's test this. `Did @LightnessRacesinOrbit receive a notification?`

Comment: @HermannDöppes: Well... blimey!