# Bug: Cannot write a comment with Java annotations

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

When I tried to write a comment with Java annotations, it thought I was trying to reference users and wouldn't let me submit.

[image]

Please remove the error and let me type whatever comment I want.

Comment: Does it do this if you wrap them in backticks, to denote code? It would make sense to use that in this case, it looks like.

Comment: Just wrap them in backticks, it'll be more readable too: `@EnableAuthorizationServer`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a better demonstration would have included 2 `@annotations` in `@backticks`.  Plus an actual user ping.

Comment: bla bla bla bla foo bar baz qux `@something` `@somethingelse`

Comment: Yep, it works as long as you include the backticks.

Comment: @ryanyuyu do you have such an example handy?.... OOOOH I SEE WHAT YOU DID THERE!

Comment: Chloe, I would suggest framing a feature request more from an angle of "Here is the benefit to the site and why it would help".... the way you framed it makes it sound really entitled, which may not fly well with the meta regulars

Comment: `@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableAuthorizationServer` works.

Comment: \@EnableResourceServer

Comment: `Did @Mulliganaceous get this notification?`

Comment: I did it unfortunately \@user202729 \@anotheruser...

Comment: @Mulliganaceous (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363419/a-dot-makes-mentions-work-funny) for more details, your suggested solution doesn't always work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments, an at-sign @ (before a space) means notifying to a given user, unless it is within a code segment using backticks. This is not a bug.

You cannot notify more than one user in a comment. **Enclose all the Java annotations in backticks.** In your screenshot you provided, you notified the (likely nonexistant) user @EnableResourceServer and @EnableAuthorizationServer.

See [A dot makes mentions (`@`) work funny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363419/a-dot-makes-mentions-work-funny) for more details about the behavior of the at-sign in comments, and when it is a notification.

Comment: I used a backslash.